# DDD logic and Persistence Ignorance

Tags: c#, .net, orm, domain-driven-design, persistence

Consider the following scenario:

```
public class Document 
{
  private ISet<User> sharedWith;

  public Document(string name) 
  {
    this.sharedWith = new HashSet<User>();
    this.Name = name;
  }

  public string Name { get; private set; }

  public IEnumerable<User> SharedWith 
  {
    get 
    {      
      return this.sharedWith;
    }
  }

  public void ShareWith(User user) 
  {
    if (this.SharedWith.Contains(user)) 
    {      
      throw new Exception("This document is already shared with that user.");
    }

    this.sharedWith.Add(user);
  }
}
```

- `Documents` can be shared with `User`
- When sharing a document with a user, if the document has already been shared with that user, throw an exception.
- Documents can be shared with 10's of thousands of users.

Obviously this does not scale very well, because of the need to check the `SharedWith` for user existence, resulting in the ORM lazy-loading the entire  collection into memory. I *could* do the existence check in the application service, but I consider this domain logic, and so it makes the most sense to me that I keep it in the Document class.

I can't seem to figure out how this should be done with DDD? And what if I am unable to use an ORM, how does one do this sort of stuff?

I suppose I should have a *Document Aggregate* and a *User Aggregate*?

I've looked at various DDD resources (I have not read the book though), but I can't seem to find an answer to this particular scenario.

Comment: this type of logic could/should belong within a domain service. just another tactical pattern for dealing with things like this. your repo could have a simple method return a bool on whether a doc has been shared with a specific user

Comment: @Marco then I have failed to understand what kind of logic should go in the domain classes themselves? Isn't what I described called domain logic?

Comment: the consistency boundary an aggregate enforces is its invariants. did your business users *really* say this is a business rule or is this something you came up with yourself?

Comment: also you could use double dispatch and the user passed in could contain a collection of document ids its shared with and the document could do the check there

Comment: I came up with this - `the consistency boundary an aggregate enforces is its invariants` not sure what this means?

Comment: @Marco doing that does not feel very... business'y. I think I've misunderstood what a domain class may and may not do.

Comment: here is a type of invariant - an order must always contain a shipping address. this must always be enforced and in a transactionaly consistent state.

Comment: remember you are not modeling the real world - just composing a bunch of objects. you need to evaluate each use case and behaviors and model from there

Comment: So, *a document can not be shared with the same user more than once* is also an invariant?

Comment: I've always thought that the point of Domain classes was to have properties and methods that map to real world stuff?

Comment: yes that can be considered an invariant but you also noticed a performance impact that could cause on the system and impede its ability to scale. so having a domain service fits the bill nicely.

Comment: they do map real world concepts but how the aggregate is composed using  value objects and entities is defined around the invariants that need to be enforced.

Comment: So domain services may also perform domain behavior? What kind of behavior should my domain classes contain then? Would you mind replicating my example in an acceptable DDD way? I think that will help my understanding tremendously.

Comment: domain services contain domain logic that does not naturally fit within your  aggregate for example business rules that span multiple aggregates. without knowing all your business rules you could have your user class have a method that takes in a document object and the user could check its internal collection of document ids to see if it is already being shared with

Comment: @Marco the user may also have 10000+ documents, resulting in the same issue.

Comment: will if thats the case you need a domain service :)
it's all about trade-offs

Comment: @Marco this does make sense, but it seems it would lead me back to the anemic domain model, where the domain classes do not have any behavior at all. Whats different? :)

Comment: well, when constructing a document i'm sure it has certain attributes that must always be consistent (document must always have a name) and business rules like "document can only be shared when it is published"

Comment: @Marco ah, so the domain service would then check `IsPublished` before doing what it does?

Comment: yes. your domain service could first check and make sure it is published. if it is, it could then ask the repository if the user already is associated with the document. if so, continue on with the happy path :) however, the aggregate still needs to perform the check on whether or not it is published before allowing the user to be added. so you should just have your domain service call the sharewith method on the document and let the exception bubble up. you want to "Tell don't ask"

Comment: @Marco would you mind providing an answer with a code example of how you envision this? :)

Comment: Why would re-sharing an already shared document raise an exception? That sounds like a bad design decision.

Comment: @StephanEggermont it was just an example to demonstrate the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was quickly done up so it's not perfect but you get the gist of it:

```
public class User { public Guid UserId { get; set; } }

public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private ICollection<User> sharedWith = new List<User>();

    private DateTime? publishedOn;

    public Document(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Name is required");
        }

        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void Publish()
    {
        if (this.publishedOn.HasValue == false)
        {
            this.publishedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }

    public void SharedWith(User user)
    {
        if (this.publishedOn.HasValue == false)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Document must be published for sharing is allowed.");
        }

        sharedWith.Add(user);
    }
}

public interface IDocumentRepository
{
    Document documentOfId(Guid id);

    bool IsAlreadySharedWith(Guid documentId, Guid userId);
}

public interface IUseRepository
{
    User userOfId(Guid id);
}

public class ShareDocumentService
{
    private readonly IUseRepository userRepository;
    private readonly IDocumentRepository documentRepository;

    public void ShareWith(Guid userId, Guid documentId)
    {
        if (documentRepository.IsAlreadySharedWith(documentId, userId))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Document has already been shared with user.");

        User user = userRepository.userOfId(userId);

        Document doc = documentRepository.documentOfId(documentId);

        doc.SharedWith(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79562/discussion-on-answer-by-marco-ddd-logic-and-persistence-ignorance).

Comment: So much to change, and I have tests for everything as well, so thats like 4x more work!

Comment: Now that I no longer have references between entities, how do I map this to relationships in my SQL db? Sorry for dragging this out :P

Comment: This is the approach I went with.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you were modelling this in a paper/actor based world, then someone would have the job of marshalling who has access to which document(s) and this would probably rely on some sort of paper based artefact.  To gain access to a document you would have to fill out a Document Request Form, which might go through an approval process.

This form in a paper based world, would become the many-to-many linking entity that becomes the key to user's accessing secure documents.  It would make `User`, `Document` and `DocumentRequestForm` three separate entities.

Comment: In my case, it's as simple as specified in the question. However, I don't see how splitting it into a `DocumentRequestForm` solves the need of having to load the collection into memory?

Comment: @Jeff I'd really make it a `DocumentSharing` aggregate root, but the idea is the same. It solves the need of having to load the collection because `Document` doesn't have a direct reference to the `Users` it was shared with any more. Everything is in `DocumentSharing` which as an Aggregate Root has its own Repository, allowing you to know if a given sharing already exists. Also, the links are modelled as ID references (which is recommended for Aggregate to Aggregate relations) instead of full object references.

Comment: @guillaume31 I have not been able to find a concrete example of an aggregate root, would you mind providing a small example of how a `DocumentSharing` aggregate? It sounds like what I need.

Comment: `DocumentSharing` is a great name for it.  An Aggregate Root is either an entity or a tree of entities (which may or may not contain any number of value objects).  In the `Order` example, the `Order` entity would contain a collection of `OrderItem` entities, but the `OrderItem` entities would not be accessible or retrievable from your database.  They would have no context without the `Order`, so the `Order` Aggregate Root would be loaded/saved/modified as one object.  I.e. `Order` would have a repository, whereas `OrderItem` would not.

Comment: @guillaume31 would your `DocumentSharing` AR reference the `User` and `Document` by id?

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips Yes. Since "Documents can be shared with 10's of thousands of users" I would make Sharing an Aggregate Root. Don't know if it was exactly your idea. You could also make it a simple list of Document IDs in the `User` aggregate root if number of sharings per user is not too high, I guess.

Comment: @guillaume31 Yes that's pretty much what I was imagining.

Comment: @Jeff something along these lines : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e78709d784749e04da2d

Comment: @guillaume31 So I would not set up a DB relationship for this to work? I don't understand why the DocumentSharing would be an AR, since a Document can exist without any shares, so wouldn't the Document be the AR?

Comment: @Jeff A lot of details were intentionally omitted :) That a Document can exist without any shares has nothing to do with it being an aggregate root or not. See Vaughn Vernon's work for a good approach to aggregate design : http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

Comment: @guillaume31 I've been through that but fail to see how I can apply it to this?

Comment: Just don't put things together (in same Aggregate) by default, but only put together what absolutely has to change together simultaneously. There's a step by step approach here : https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=926

Comment: Does a `Sharing` change each time its `Document` or its `User` changes ? No, there's no transactional continuity between them, so no reason to put them in the same aggregate. Plus you'll avoid loading collections with thousands of shares in them.

Comment: @guillaume31 i dont suppose RDB's make sense for DDD?

Comment: @guillaume31 by only referencing by IDs, i cant set up relationships in my ORM. Im getting the feeling that ORM's are not suited for DDD.

Comment: You don't need to set up navigatable relationships between aggregates. By definition, they are hydrated / persisted / deleted at different times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79740/discussion-between-guillaume31-and-jeff).